# preg_replace заменить в строке символы, а цифры оставить

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Есть строка в php допустим $str = 'z1.z2.z3.z6'
Как привести её к такому виду '[f1][f2][f3][f6]' через регулярку используя preg_replace ???
То есть везде заменить z на f, но соответствующие числа оставить и заключить выражение в квадратные скобки.

Comment: квадратные скобки тоже нужны в результате замены?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$str = 'z1.z2.z3.z6';
echo preg_replace('/z(\d+)(.|$)/i', '[f${1}]', $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Ещё один вариант

```
$string = 'z1.z2.z3.z6';
$symbol = 'f'; // Символ для замены

$pattern = ['~\w(\d)~', '~(?<=^|\.)~', '~(?=\.|$)~', '~\.~'];
$replace = [$symbol .'$1', '[', ']', ''];

echo preg_replace($pattern, $replace, $string);

// Результат: [f1][f2][f3][f6]
```

Comment: А поделитесь пожалуйста ссылкой на то, что написано в `$pattern`. Буду признателен.

Comment: @Максим Буяков ссылок к сожалению нет, шаблоны пишу на основе знаний, полученных после чтения книги "Джеффри Фридла" - "Регулярные выражения". Рекомендую ;-)